# Ubuntu 15.04 unity - All windows always on top

Tags: unity, window

I'm experiencing a window issue on Ubuntu 15.04 on Unity.
All my windows are always on top. For instance, if I have a folder window opened before Firefox, when I click on the Firefox window, the folder stays opened ahead. 
It used to happen with 14.10 already. Of course, the "always on top" option is not checked...

Comment: I'm still having this problem.  I tried to switch to Gnome with no effect, so I guess it's not related to Unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I foud the answer !

- Install dconf-editor
- Go to org->gnome->desktop->wm->preferences
- Activate "Raise on click"